# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1} = 4$ using the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

> Prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1} = 4$$ using the epsilon-delta definition of the limit of a function.

I'm not sure how to find a delta, I should be fine from there. The whole proof would be amazing.

Comment: You tagged this _proof-verification_, but where is your attempt? Then we can verify it and give suggestions ;-). Also: try to use proper formatting, there's mathjax for equations.

Comment: Why would you need to use $\epsilon - \delta $? This can be proven using the definition of limit of sequence, which states "for all $\epsilon > 0$there exists an $N$ such that $n>N $ implies $ |(4n^2-1)/(n^2+n+1) - 4| < \epsilon$"

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is a sequence and then proving:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1} = 4$$
means you need to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you can find an $N$ such that:
$$n \ge N \implies \left| \frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}-4 \right| < \varepsilon$$
Since $n>0$, you can simplify:
$$\left| \frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}-4 \right| = \left| -\frac{4n+5}{n^2+n+1} \right|= \frac{4n+5}{n^2+n+1}$$
Now you can try to solve the inequality:
$$\frac{4n+5}{n^2+n+1} < \varepsilon$$
but that's a bit annoying. Alternatively, look for an upper bound first:
$$\frac{4n+5}{n^2\color{red}{+n+1}} \le \frac{4n+5\color{blue}{n}}{n^2} = \frac{9n}{n^2}=\frac{9}{n}$$
Can you finish? If not, hoover over:

> $$\displaystyle \left| \frac{4n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}-4 \right| = \frac{4n+5}{n^2+n+1} \le \frac{9}{n} \quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{9}{n} < \varepsilon \iff n > \ldots\quad\mbox{so pick $N \ldots$}$$